# How to Set Chromedriver cookies which collected from http request c#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, httprequest, httpresponse

I am first connecting website using http request response and collecting cookies in cookiecontainer . now i want to set that cookie to chrome driver and open web page using selenium in c#

Please Help me for that

How to Set Chromedriver cookies which collected from http request using c#

Comment: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/browser/cookies/  (You'll need to navigate to the domain of the cookies before setting them.)